# Is ASP.NET framework part of CLR or BCL?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I started up with learning `.NET` and `C#` fundamentals and now I think I am clear with them.

So I thought to study `ASP.NET MVC` web development framework. In most of the books and tutorials I see, I just get to know that it is a web development framework.

Talking in terms of .NET framework,where does it exactly fit in, I mean is it a part of `CLR` or part of huge number of classes in `BCL`?

Comment: It's just a part of .NET.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MVC is not part of the CLR but executed by CLR as any other .NET code. The Common Language Runtime (CLR) is the virtual machine component of .NET framework responsible for managing the execution of .NET programs.

MVC is not part of BCL but use it. The Base Class Library (BCL) is the common language infrastructure and contains core types and fundamental features. [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) and [ISO/IEC 23271:2006](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=42927) standards  decribe what Micorsoft consider part of the BCL.

It's just another development created using the .NET framework, not different from any .NET development you could do except for the fact that it was done by Microsoft.

You could even download MVC code if you're interested on it. More information [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Hi,By development do you mean its an API built using BCL,but not part of it.right?

Comment: @ZoomIn: that's correct. Using BCL and/ or other features not part of the BCL.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is a server-side Web application framework designed for Web development to produce dynamic Web pages. ASP.NET is built on the Common Language Runtime (CLR), allowing programmers to write ASP.NET code using any supported .NET language.

- Common Language Runtime is the backbone of the .NET framework and The Common Language Runtime (CLR) is the virtual machine component of Microsoft's .NET framework and is responsible for managing the execution of .NET programs
- The Common Language Runtime (CLR) is an Execution Environment . It works as a layer between Operating Systems and the applications written in .Net languages that conforms to the Common Language Specification (CLS). The main function of Common Language Runtime (CLR) is to convert the Managed Code into native code and then execute the Program